# How can I Delete Files That Do Not Contain Certain Characters Using Windows Batch File?

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-io

How can I delete files that do not end with the pattern `.PDF_*.pdf` ?

```
AA00A6E2.PDF
AA00A6E3.PDF
AA00A6E3.PDF_01.pdf
AA00A6E3.PDF_02.pdf
AA00A6E3.PDF_03.pdf
```

I have been trying all sorts of variations around the following syntax:

```
FOR %%F IN (%varFolderSource%\*.*) DO IF NOT "%%~xF" == "*_*" DEL /F /S "%%F"
```

But I can't seem to crack it.

```
%varFolderSource% is a folder path: C:\Temp etc.
```

I am running this in a Windows 7 batch file.

Comment: What error etc have you been getting, can you print out from your FOR loop rather than try to delete to see what it is matching?  More information please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
For /f "delims=" %A in ('dir /b /a-d ^|findstr /i /v /e /r "\.PDF_[a-z0-9]*\.pdf"') do echo %A
```

Type

```
for /?
findstr /?
```

In a batch file use `%%A` rather than `%A` at command prompt.

Comment: +1 The regular expression should use `.*` where you have `[a-z0-9]*`  While the `/i` is a case insensitive switch I think the character class would still need to include `A-Z` and it would then still exclude special characters.

Comment: /c does work for upper case filename parts. Just tested. I actually started with all legal file name characters. Till I saw they are named 01, 02, ..., 0n. I meant to take a-z out.

Comment: For /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d ^|findstr /i /v /e /r "\.PDF_[a-z0-9]*\.pdf"') do DEL %%A worked perfectly. Thankyou Noodles and Foxidrive for your help.